# How to use Character subscript in Swift 3.1?

Tags: swift, swift3, subscript

I'm new to Swift. I found out some weird behavior of subscript matching:

```
struct SubscriptTest {
    subscript(character: Character) -> String {
        return "Character: \(character)"
    }

    subscript(string: String) -> String {
        return "String: \(string)"
    }

    subscript(int: Int) -> String {
        return "Int: \(int)"
    }
}

let test = SubscriptTest()
test["abc"] // String: abc
test[13] // Int: 13
test[""] // String:  (surprisingly)
```

I thought the last test would match my `Character` subscript, not the `String` one. I tried to swap the order of subscripts declarations, thinking that maybe the last matching one is being used. It didn't change anything, `String` subscript is still used for single `Character`.

I know I could just use `String` subscript and check for characters count, but the root of my question is curiosity.

Why is `Character` subscript never matched here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`""` can be both a `String` literal and a `Character` literal,
and defaults to `String` (if both are valid in the context). With

```
test["" as Character] // Character:
```

or

```
let c: Character = ""
test[c] // Character:
```

you get the expected result.

Comment: So is there something like type priority in Swift?

Comment: @RoboRobok: There is a default type for literals.  `123` can be a `Int` or `Float` or `Double` or `UInt64` or ... . It is taken as `Int` if nothing else can be inferred from the context.

Comment: I love Swift more and more :)

Comment: And just for fun (don't do this in production code), you could define `typealias UnicodeScalarType = Character; typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterType = Character` to change the default literal type for unicode scalar and character literals from `String` to `Character` :D Then `test[""]` would call the `Character` subscript.

Comment: The above works because when there's no other context to infer a type for a literal, the compiler searches for a default type with a given name that's in scope. The standard library defines types for these, but we can override them. These default names for each ExpressibleBy*Literal protocol are listed here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Sema/TypeCheckExpr.cpp#L562

Comment: That's very interesting, @Hamish! Thank you for letting me know :)